# EC2Connection.run_instance fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to spin up an ec2 instance using boto. But I run into the problem

```
e.run_instances(AMI_ID, key_name='lappy', instance_type='m1.small',    security_group_ids=['sg-4bf11724'])
```

Where e is `EC2Connection` object.

The error I get is

```
EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>VPCIdNotSpecified</Code><Message>No default VPC for this user</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>a88020d7-a284-4897-9f18-7329c8cbe312</RequestID> </Response>
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Any chance your security group sg-4bf11724 belongs to VPC and not EC2?

Comment: You have probably deleted your default VPC subnet, so you will have to specify subnet_id.